# Need help installing libgraph library on ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: command-line, apt, 20.04, package-management, 22.04

I am new to Ubuntu. I am trying to install libgraph to use
`#include <graphics.h>`
in my school c++ programs.

I have ubuntu 22.04 LTS (jammy jellyfish).

The online tutorials ask to install guile  2.0-dev but it is no longer included in the 22.04LTS (it was upgraded to guile 2.2-dev). Hence, I get the following error:

```
Package guile-2.0 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source.
```

How do I install libgraph using guile 2.2 ? if it is possible.

If not, then is there any other method to install libgraph (maybe manually installing guile 2.0?)

I don't have an extensive understanding of terminal and need layman explanations.

Can anybody please give me the commands which I can directly paste in the Terminal?